# Can Imagick Class read in video file and extract an image?

Tags: video, imagick

We have a website hosted by a well-known host. The feature we'd like to achieve is very simple: when an user uploads a video like mp4, we'd like the site to read in the video file and extract an image as thumbnail image.

So far we are unable to do it:
1. we know ffmpeg can do it. But our host told us it is not allowed to install ffmpeg (actually any customer requested software) on host side.
2. we know ImageMagick can do it. It is actually already installed. But our host told us exec and shell_exec command is not allowed. so we can't run something like "exec convert" to invoke ImageMagick.
3. Imagick class is also installed. But to our understanding, imagick is to handle static image and not video. Actually we already gave it a try on mp4 video and it didn't work. But we'd like to confirm with the community. Hopefully we are wrong.

If 3 doesn't work, any other way to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: i) ImageMagick can only read video by using ffmpeg as a 'delegate' library ii) Shared hosting where you cannot install software is not a valid place to do video processing. You need to get a VPS server which cost about $10 a month.